# Pycharm Jupyter Notebook Markdown Display Fuzzy Font

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I encountered a problem while trying to use Pycharm for editing Jupyter Notebook file. I found the preview for markdown section is quite terrible. The font is really dizzy compared with code section. Besides, table can't be correctly displayed. Here is a snapshot. (Sorry for not having enough reputation to upload an image.)
https://i.loli.net/2019/03/07/5c807628da013.png

My Pycharm Community Version: 2018.2.4, OS: Windows 10, Display resolution: 1080p

Did anyone have this problem before? Is there any possible solution to this? I'm really appreciate for that!

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Please add:
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false
to:
Help | Edit Custom VM Options
and restart PyCharm

( https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000640040-How-to-fix-pixelated-markdown-cells-in-Jupyter-notebooks-in-Pycharm- )

Comment: But be warned: Using scaling on Gnome with Wayland results in an unbearable large preview with this settings. To work against that you'll need to change the preview font size in the settings (Open settings and search for jupyter)